# Comma usage after a direct quote?

Tags: commas, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Punctuation of direct speech, edge cases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/punctuation-of-direct-speech-edge-cases)

> Schwimmer promised Ciccaroni “nothing would happen to any teacher of mine under my watch,” and told him not to bring any pepper spray onto school grounds.

I am having a real hard time trying to figure out if there should there be a comma in the above sentence. Can anyone please explain why there should or should not be a comma ?

Comment: If you're so worried about getting assaulted that you might have to carry pepper spray, maybe punctuation isn't your biggest problem.

Comment: I wouldn't put a comma there because it separates the subject (Schwimmer) from the second verb (told). The clause beginning with *and* is not an independent clause.

Comment: @JLG I think that makes more sense, so if I wanted to throw a comma in I would need to add she: Schwimmer promised Ciccaroni “nothing would happen to any teacher of mine under my watch,” and **she** told him not to bring any pepper spray onto school grounds.

Comment: Yes. (Not sure if Barrie England would agree with me, but that is what I would do [especially if you want to keep the direct quote as you seem to].)

Comment: Also, most 'authorities' call for a comma *before* the quote, which to my mind makes one after it virtually obligatory. (Me, I like it like it is.)

Answer (score 1):

There are bigger problems here than punctuation. The sentence is a mixture of direct and indirect speech, and you need to make it one or the other. Indirect speech might be preferable, in which case it becomes:

> Schwimmer promised Ciccaroni that nothing would happen to any teacher
>   of his under his watch, and told him not to bring any pepper spray
>   onto school grounds.

Comment: Or *promised Ciccaroni “Nothing will happen to any teacher of mine under my watch,”*

Comment: @StoneyB: I did wonder about that, but I wasn't sure that _promise_ would normally introduce a piece of direct speech. Inversion is a but unusual these days too.