# Ellipsis at the end of a quote

Tags: punctuation, ellipses, quotation-marks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Punctuation of direct speech, edge cases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/punctuation-of-direct-speech-edge-cases)
> [Space before three dots?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91653/space-before-three-dots)

> "I don't think so," she stated.
>
> "I don't think..." her voice trailed off.

Is this second sentence correct from punctuation point of view (ellipsis working along with the same rule as `?`,`!` - replacing the comma), or does it require an extra comma? (or yet something different?)

I'm aware it is normally used instead of a comma or a full stop, with very rare exceptions, but the rules of using punctuation at the end of interrupted quotes still baffle me.

Comment: This is answered at [Punctuation of direct speech, edge cases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/punctuation-of-direct-speech-edge-cases)

Comment: Bringhurst says: “In English (but usually not in French), when the ellipsis occurs at the end of a sentence, a fourth dot, the period, is added and the space at the beginning of the ellipsis disappears. . . . When the ellipsis combines with a comma, exclamation mark, or question mark, the same typographical principle applies. Otherwise, a word space is required fore and aft. The ellipsis is a graphic word.” Therefore, you are shy a comma there that you should have according to accepted typographical conversion.  The three dots you are wrong. “I don’t think so, . . .” her voice trailed off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't think so," she stated.

"I don't think..." her voice trailed off.

You have punctuated correctly. In the first sentence, the comma is essential in that it sets off an attribution--one without which, the end of the quotation, or even its presence, would be unclear (to a listener).

In the latter sentence, clearly, *her voice trailed off* is not an attribution but, simply, a phrase the modifies the preceding phrase that just happens to be, but need not have been, a direct quotation.

The latter sentence with quotation could have been written: "I don't think...," she said as her voice trailed off. In which case the attribution would not have been implicit.

Yours is an example where speech cannot always follow writing without ambiguity or *without* clear speech context, such as in story telling.