# Question marks in written conversation

Tags: questions

Should a question mark appear at the end of a question, and before the second quotation mark?

An example is:

> "How are you feeling today," he asked.

I'm getting conflicting advice.

Comment: Answered at [Punctuation of direct speech, edge cases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/punctuation-of-direct-speech-edge-cases), in particular [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/punctuation-of-direct-speech-edge-cases/73221#73221): "Where you're reporting a trailing-off of speech, or some other ending, the punctuation mark isn't a full-stop so it doesn't become a comma."

Comment: Punctuation in reported speech should report the speech, not hew to artificial conventions. The ending of a _Wh_-question **is** a full-stop; it's indistinguishable from a period in speech. The end rise of intonation only occurs on _Yes/No_ questions, not on _Wh_-questions. So there should be a question mark **before** the end quotation mark -- the quote marks the end of speech, and the full-stop intonation is part of the speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler What's a *Wh*-question? One beginning "Which/What"? Are you saying that questions only need question marks when the (expected) answer is *Yes/No*? So "What is your native language?" shouldn't have a "?" at the end?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if one is reporting speech, and the speech is a question, then it should be marked as a question. I.e, question mark, not comma; and question mark before close quote. I only mentioned "full-stop" intonation because it was in the previous comment.

Comment: @TrevorD English has [more *wh-* words than just those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word#In_English).

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is

> "How are you feeling today?" he asked.

This is because the part in quotation marks is a *question*, so it should have a question mark, but the entire sentence is simply a statement.