# Proper punctuation of broken dialogue

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

What is the proper punctuation for broken dialogue? I have the following line:

> "I just never expected you to be so—" she looked Dan up and down "—human," she finished.

I believe that is the correct way to write that, but I'm not sure. Is there a comma before the dialogue resumes? Do I need spaces before and after the dashes, or are they right next to the words like I have them?

If you could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: There may not be a “correct” answer, just varying examples of what can be found in print.

Comment: There is a related question though: [Punctuation of direct speech, edge cases](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73221/18696), at least one answer to which contains similar advice to RJC's answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An em dash is usually used only when the dialogue is broken in the middle of a word.

> "As I was trying to expl—"

For your example it would be customary to surround the break with em dashes, like so:

> "I just never expected you to be so"—she looked Dan up and down—"human," she finished.

Comment: I'm guessing that spaces around the dashes are writer preference?

Comment: Newspapers typically insert spaces while literary authors typically don't.